# how to navigate or call ant .js file in titanium

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

hey all, 
        how to navigate/call other .js file after click event on button. once it ciick it will goes to other window. osplease help me to solve this problem

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below a quick sample, focused around iOS.  There are a bunch more available in the Kitchen Sink example App available here:
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/tree/master/demos/KitchenSink

Steps:

1) Create Titanium Mobile Project

2) In the app.js file add the below

```
var winPage1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url:'page1.js', title:'Page 1'
});

winPage1.open();
```

3) Add a file in the same directory as app.js called page1.js, then paste this in

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

(function(){
    var b1 = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title : 'Press Me',
        left : 10, top : 100, right : 10, height : 40
    });
    b1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var wPage = Ti.UI.createWindow({ 
                title:'Test Page2',
                backgroundColor:'yellow',
                url:'page2.js'
        });

        wPage.open({modal:false});
    });

    win.add(b1);

})();
```

4) Add a file in the same directory as app.js called page2.js, then paste this in

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

(function(){
    var b1 = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title : 'Press Me',
        left : 10, top : 100, right : 10, height : 40
    });
    b1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        win.close();
    });

    win.add(b1);

})();
```

5) Run in Titanium Developer or Studio

This should give you a running same showing how to open and close windows.  Kitchen Sink (link above) has a ton more samples showing different ways to do this.